# Hide the tag-info popup

Tags: script, questions, tags

This script hides the tag info popup. In response to [*Why are there popups over tags in the question page?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/74470/why-are-there-popups-over-tags-in-the-question-page).

[Install](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/97857.user.js)

[View Source](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/97857)